# I am trying to have customized error pages - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: php, apache, xampp

I am using xampp which has Apache 2.4.3.  In the file xampp/apache/conf/httpd.conf I have set "AllowOverride All".  In xampp/htdocs/.htaccess I have set "ErrorDocument 500 /InitialError.php".
InitialError.php is a file that for now is just echoing out some simple html.  In my file xampp/htdocs/index.php I have the line "$new = new unknownclass();"  where the class unknownclass is undefined.

When I run the index.php file all I am seeing is the error message 
"Fatal error: Class 'unknownclass' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 3" and if display_errors is false I do not see anything.

Is there something else I need to be setting?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that with htaccess.

Something along the lines of:

Apache: ah a php request, thats php's job

PHP: I got this.

Apache: Ok I am going home.

PHP: shit I dont got this.

Its PHP's problem to return a error page.

if something goes bad within apache the page should work!

PS check

http://php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php

Comment: OK.  I was hoping to use the customized 500 error page to email the administrator if the program was unable to initialize, which includes loading my error handling routines.  Any slicker ideas other than putting a specialized error handling function in the index.php file.